# Using a python script with MERN application

Tags: python, node.js, json, mern, spawn

I'm trying to run a python script. The results of the script is a long list of dictionaries that I have converted to a json object.

But I can't seem to run it with the backend since it throws me this error:
Error occurred while parsing scraped data SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at Socket. (/Users/dhruv/Desktop/myTravelApp/server/server.js:180:30)
here is the backend code:

```
app.get("/scrape", auth, (req, res) => {
  const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
  const pythonProcess = spawn("python", ["./script.py"]);

  let scrapedData = "";

  pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    scrapedData += data;
  });

  pythonProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.error(data.toString());
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
  });

  pythonProcess.stdout.on("end", function () {
    try {
      const jsonArray = JSON.parse(scrapedData);
      const parsedData = jsonArray.map((item) => JSON.parse(item));
      res.json({ data: parsedData });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occurred while parsing scraped data", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
    }
  });
});
```